# Asp.net Core 3.1 MVC Ajax call to method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this method in my controller:

```
public async Task<string> AjaxMethod() 
{
//some codes

var jsonResults = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
return jsonResults;

}
```

I have ajax call to this method and it works that i expected.

I realize that when i access to this method via url (like localhost:50000/Controller/AjaxMethod) it shows all data on web browser and i dont want this.

What is the best approach to prevent this issue?

additional info : i am using asp.net identity and my controller has [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken] attribute at top.

Comment: There is no way you can prevent this, actions without authorization shouldn't expose sensitive data, if you wish to return data that shouldn't be viewed by anyone, decorate your action with the `Authorize` attribute and apply an appropriate role.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your action to post like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> AjaxMethod() 
{
//some codes

var jsonResults = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
return jsonResults;

}
```

and then in your ajax use :

```
type: "POST",
```

so that you cannot use localhost：50000 / Controller / AjaxMethod to get data in browser.